# C++ class template function can access nested class private member

Tags: c++, templates, private, instantiation

The following code fails to compile as expected:

```
#include<iostream>
class Enclosing {
    int x;
    class Nested { int y; };

    void EnclosingFun(Nested *n) {
        std::cout << n->y;  // Compiler Error: y is private in Nested
    }
};
```

However, if I change EnclosingFun into a template member function, the compiler (gcc-7) doesn't complain about accessing y:

```
#include<iostream>
class Enclosing {      
    int x;
    class Nested { int y; };

    template <typename T>
    void EnclosingFun(Nested *n, T t) {
        std::cout << t << n->y;  // OK? Why?
    }      
};
```

Is this a bug in gcc? Or does c++ have different access rules for template member function to access nested classes?

Comment: You never called it, this the function is not instantiated. Add call in the main.

Comment: @S.M. you should expand that to an answer.

Comment: @RSahu Ok, I expanded my comment to the answer. But it is already answered before me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this a bug in gcc? Or does c++ have different access rules for template member function to access nested classes?

No either.

According to the standard, [§17.8.1 Implicit instantiation [temp.inst]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#10),

> An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate a function template, a variable template, a member template, a non-virtual member function, a member class, a static data member of a class template, or a substatement of a constexpr if statement ([stmt.if]), unless such instantiation is required.

That means, `Enclosing::EnclosingFun()` is not instantiated here. Adding the invocation to it would cause it to be instantiated, then you'll get the error, e.g.

```
prog.cc:8:30: error: 'int Enclosing::Nested::y' is private within this context
         std::cout << t << n->y;  // OK? Why?
                           ~~~^
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XvYc1CcTlCFJt6Sv)

Comment: This is actually extremely useful. For example, if I am writing `std::vector<T>`, `resize` doesn't work if `T` doesn't have a default constructor. Fortunately, I can just write `resize` as if `T` did, and the code will compile as long as the user doesn't use `resize`

Answer (score 3):

It is not a bug in GCC. You do not call your function template, therefore the function is not instantiated, and it does not try to access the private member of the nested class. Try to call your function somewhere in a real function (not template) or try to refer it (implicit instantiation).

> A function template by itself is not a type, or a function, or any other entity. No code is generated from a source file that contains only template definitions. In order for any code to appear, a template must be instantiated: the template arguments must be determined so that the compiler can generate an actual function (or class, from a class template).
>
> When code refers to a function in context that requires the function definition to exist, and this particular function has not been explicitly instantiated, implicit instantiation occurs.

```
template void Enclosing::EnclosingFun(Enclosing::Nested *n, int t); // instantiates the function for the second int parameter
```