# Why isn't it possible to use CRTP's types, but possible to call CRTP's methods?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

This code compiles and works only when calling CRTP's methods:

```
template <typename CRTP>
struct crtp
{
    // using type = typename CRTP::type; // will not compile
    void print() const
    {
        using type = typename CRTP::type; // compiles
        static_cast<const CRTP&>(*this).print();
    }
};

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    struct foo : crtp<foo>
    {
        using type = int;
        void print() const {
            std::cout << "John Cena\n";
        };
    } f{};

    const crtp<foo>& c = f;
    c.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Upon `crtp<foo>`'s instantiation, foo is incomplete. But its methods can be used.

However, CRTP's types can't used dues CRTP's incompleteness outside functions.

**Why is it allowed to defer a check for incompletness until a class's function is called, but not upon object's instatiation?**

---

When `using CRTP::type` within the class body (uncommented), one will get a compilation error:

```
<source>:4:33: error: no type named 'type' in 'foo'
    using type = typename CRTP::type; // will not compile
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
```

Comment: its unclear what code you refer to that does not compile. I dont have to call the method for it to "work" https://godbolt.org/z/PPobWof8G

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number https://godbolt.org/z/x67Y6EPaW just uncomment the line with `// will not compile`

Comment: Two phase compilation of templates probably has a lot to do with it

Comment: @john is this a standard-defined behavior? Any details?

Comment: not my downvote, but imho the question would be so much more clear if you would post the complete example of the code that does not compile and include the error message in the question.

Comment: "Upon crtp<foo>'s instantiation, foo is incomplete. " maybe you overlook that `foo` inherits from `crtp<foo>` hence needs `ctrp<foo>` to be complete. Its somewhat a chicken and egg problem, the reason it works is that `crtp` needs `foo` not to be complete (unless you call the method)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56891571/817643

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49216371/817643

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica https://stackoverflow.com/q/56891571/817643 answers the question

Answer (score 2):

Note that even if you write a member function definition inside the class template definition, it is not instantiated when the class template is instantiated.

`foo` can't be defined until its base class `crtp<foo>` has been completely defined, but the type alias in the definition of `crtp<foo>`  requires `foo`'s definition to be known, which requires `crtp<foo>` to already be defined, which requires `foo`, and so on...

Member functions, on the other hand, are not compiled until after their class has been fully defined, so the type alias is fine there.
(That is, instantiating `void crtp<foo>::print() const` works because it only happens after `foo` has been defined and `crtp<foo>` has been instantiated.)

Separating the class template definition from the member function definition makes the two phases clearer:

```
template <typename CRTP>
struct crtp
{
    // Can't compile unless CRTP is defined at this point.
    using type = typename CRTP::type; 
    void print() const;
};


template <typename CRTP>
void crtp<CRTP>::print() const
{
    // Also can't compile unless CRTP is defined at this point, but
    // this is a later point than the class definition.
    using type = typename CRTP::type;
    static_cast<const CRTP&>(*this).print();
}
```

Comment: clearer indeed.

Comment: Is it possible to trick the compiler with SFINAE to use the types within CRTP's body?

Comment: You can *"inverse"* relation ship with external type_trait: `typename <typename T> struct inner_type; template <> struct inner_type<class foo /*incomplete*/> { using type = int; };` and use `typename inner_type<CRTP>::type;`.

Comment: A very nasty "add another level of indirection" version I found (by trial and error) is `using type = typename std::remove_reference<decltype(declval<CRTP>())>::type;`, but I can't explain why that worked so I'm not even sure that it should...

Answer (score 1):

Within CRTP, derived classes are incomplete:

```
struct foo : crtp<foo> // foo incomplete here
{
    using type = int;
    void print() const {
        // foo complete here
        std::cout << "John Cena\n";
    }
}; // foo complete here
```

`foo` is also complete in `void crtp<foo>::print() const`.

Comment: That I have noticed and stated in the question. THe question boils down to why is it allowed to be complete within a function body, but not within a class body, given the class has not been instantiated. What is the reasoning behind that logic?

Comment: basically I have in my question "Why is A allowed but not B", and your answer is "A is allowed, B is not"